# AngularJS: Throwing an event via ($emit or $broadcast) from directive to controller it fails to update values that are bounded to html

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to throw an event from my directive i.e

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on('blur', function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("emit:dateTimePicker", {
                    location: scope.location,
                    action: 'changed',
                    dateTime: scope.dateTime
        });
    });
}
```

However, when it get cought in the controller

```
$scope.$on('$broadcast:dateTimePicker', function (e, value) {
    $scope.vm.dateTime = value.dateTime;
    $scope.vm.message = "Change!";
    console.log($scope.vm.dateTime);
});
```

Console write out the changed values however, the values that are bound to the html elements do not. What am I doing wrong. Sorry if this questions is not worded correctly - any hints/help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the html
`<pre >{{vm}}</pre>`

Comment: After $emit, follow by $apply or $digest.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the event handler in a `$scope.apply()` block, as:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on('blur', function () {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            $rootScope.$emit("emit:dateTimePicker", ...);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Getting: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on scope.apple(function(){.....});

Comment: Its scope.$apply() with a $-Sign in front.

Comment: got it, also emit does not work in context, had to change it to broadcast

Answer (score 0):

Add scope.$apply(); after $rootScope.$broadbast("emit:dateTimePicker", { })